# Firefox (54.0.1 (64-Bit)) DOM Inspector: Cannot Pick Dom Elements after Ajax Rerender

Tags: javascript, ajax, firefox, dom, firefox-developer-tools

Since the new DevTools of Firefox came out iI have this Problem on multible PCs:

1. I open a Webpage and inspect the DOM
2. I trigger an AJAX call or some DOM Creation by JavaScript and place the new elements into the DOM
3. I Can't pick the new Elements anymore and they are gray and not light blue. (sometimes the HTML Tag gets picked)
4. the elements are shown in the DOM inspector

[image: grey field not blue]

I can't find any bug report or option to change this behavior. There are any information about this?

Comment: Those elements are gray as they are _hidden_.

Comment: As you see the gray box isn't hidden. Its opacity is 0.8 and it is visible on the left and has display block!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The same is happening for me as well. I have tried by best to find a fix or know more about this.

Unfortunately no one has posted anything about this issue in any of the forums. I would definitely say this is a **bug in Firefox**.

I suggest you to downgrade your browser version until firefox releases a fix or next stable version. Meantime you can use [Chrome browser](https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/desktop/index.html) if you're confortable.

Comment: Thank you for confirming this :-) First I thought it happen because in upgrade from 32bit to 64bit. But now it seems to be clearly a FF bug. ... I can debug with chrome as well but some customers have Firefox bugs and it is pretty annoying ti debug like this.